# Maximum current to the circuit

Tags: power-supply, inductor, wireless-charging

The schematic of the wireless power transmitter is shown [image], The circuit works good. The inductor connected between circled nodes 1 and 1 is 24uH.

(Note: both the inputs of FET are not shorted, they are turned ON by the driver)
My input voltage and current to my circuit are 5V and 3A , maximum rated values of the adapter. (The driver is powered separately from a microcontroller board). When I observe my input power to the system, current drawn by the system is maximum 1A, when at resonance frequency. My [MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44zpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356722836272a) can allow upto 51A of current.

How can I feed more current into my system? What affects the current input to the system?
(My inductor coil is the coil used for standard wireless charging device)

Comment: You can not feed whatever you want to the system, Its the circuit which decide how much current it has to consume. If Johny wants to eat 1 apple, he will eat 1 apple only, whether you offer 5 or 10 doesn't matter.

Comment: What voltage levels are you applying on the PWM input? Are your two MOSFETS actually identical and both NMOS types? What circuit/instrument/device are you using for the 5 V supply?

Comment: @AKR, if he actually turns those two NMOS on at the same time, he should be able to pull 10's of amps. Not sure what good it would do, though, to short the supply directly to ground.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I appreciate your thoughts Photon, but shorting will actually destroy the circuit, which I think, even Sristi would not like to do :-)

Comment: @ThePhoton Both are NMOS only, The PWM input is fed through a driver which does the phase shift and turn ON upper or lower FET. My PWM voltage levels are 5V. The input 5V supply (to FET source) is through a commercial adapter with rating 5V,0-3000mA.

Comment: @AKR, well sure, but he should see the 50 A he expects, at least for a moment.

Comment: Also, you said "turns ON the upper **or** lower FET", but your circuit doesn't show the ability to turn them on seperately, only either both on or both off. Please edit your schematic to show the circuit you actually built.

Comment: For now, -1 for giving a schematic that doesn't show your actual circuit, and for not answering the question that was asked about the applied voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton, the TPS28225 is a typical half-bridge driver that takes a logic signal in on the PWM input and drives the FETs alternately with appropriate dead time to eliminate shoot-through.  I think you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @Entropivore, that part number was not mentioned until op edited the question after I commented.

Comment: @ThePhoton, sorry I didn't look at the revision history before.  Yeah, his initial posting certainly was confused, misleading, and generally a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I feed more current into my system?

First off, why do you want to feed more current into it?  Do you really mean that you want to supply more power to the receiving device?  Is the 1A current you quote with a load coupled to the inductor (I hope), or without (uh oh)?

> What affects the current input to the system? (My inductor coil is the coil used for standard wireless charging device)

Not a simple question.  With no coupled load, you'd hope that the supply current is minimal.  How the current rises when you couple a load to it depends on the load itself and how tightly it is coupled.  It looks like you have the primary side tuned to about 300kHz.  Is your input on the PWM pin a 300kHz square wave?  If the secondary (load) side is not tuned to the same frequency, the coupling will be poor.  If everything is already tuned properly and the coupling is as tight as possible, then you may have to increase the supply voltage to the output stage if you want more power.  If you keep the VDD supply at 5V, you could run the supply to the output stage up to 27V according to the TPS28225 spec.

Comment: 1A current is without load coupled to the inductor. I will try to increase the voltage supplied at output stage. Thanks

Comment: It's a little alarming that you're dumping 5 Watts into this thing with no (intentional) load.  Is any part of it getting warm?  Is there some metal in proximity to the coil that could be acting as an unintentional load?

Comment: The coil i am using is used for standard wireless charging systems. It has a ferrite sheet at the back of the coil

Comment: Here is the datasheet of the coil I am using http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/AWCCA-53N53-272891.pdf